# How do i summarize the items in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
team1   team2   winner
KKR     RCB     KKR
CSK     KXIP    CSK
RR      DD      DD
MI      KKR     KKR
DC      KKR     KKR
KXIP    RR      RR
DC      DD      DD
MI      KKR     KKR....
```

Now what exactly I want to check is how many times has a team won against another team in the tournament. For eg: MI has won 2 times against KKR. So the output should be like **MI vs KKR= MI:2 KKR:0**

I could do it manually by taking 2 teams a time but that takes a longer time. So can someone help me with this?

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: As specified above..in a dataframe

Comment: Is your "output" printed to the screen, or did you want to create a new dataframe?

Comment: Can you have `'team1': 'KKR', 'team2': 'RCB'` in one row, and `'team1': 'RCB', 'team2': 'KKR'` in another? Or is the order of the teams consistent across the entire dataset?

Comment: The order is not consistent across the dataset

Comment: Well, both answers address that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the order of teams will always be the same:

```
df.groupby(['team1','team2']).apply(lambda x: str(sum(x.winner == x.team1))+':'+str(sum(x.winner == x.team2)))
```

Without assumption, this would be solution - with df creation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'team1': ['KKR','CSK','RR','MI','DC','KXIP','DC','MI','KKR'],
                   'team2': ['RCB','KXIP','DD','KKR','KKR','RR','DD','KKR','MI'],
                   'winner': ['KKR','CSK','DD','KKR','KKR','RR','DD','KKR','MI']})


teamSort = [sorted(item) for item in df[['team1','team2']].as_matrix()]
df[['team1','team2']] = teamSort

df = df.groupby(['team1','team2']).apply(lambda x: str(sum(x.winner == x.team1))+':'+str(sum(x.winner == x.team2))).reset_index(name='score')
```

Output:

```
  team1 team2 score
0   CSK  KXIP   1:0
1    DC    DD   0:1
2    DC   KKR   0:1
3    DD    RR   1:0
4   KKR    MI   2:1
5   KKR   RCB   1:0
6  KXIP    RR   0:1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the team order is not consistent across the dataset, you need to define a `match` column:

```
df['match'] = df[['team1', 'team2']].apply(
    lambda row: tuple(sorted(row.values)), 
    axis=1
)
```

The tuple is necessary for grouping, as it is hashable.

It's not clear what output you'd like, but this should get you close to your result:

```
df.groupby('match')['winner'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
match        winner
(CSK, KXIP)  CSK       1
(DC, DD)     DD        1
...
```